# Unable to Install Amazon.ECS.Tools globally

Tags: .net, .net-core, amazon-ecs

When I run  `dotnet tool install --global Amazon.ECS.Tools --version 3.0.0` all I get is following error :

> Failed to retrieve information about 'amazon.ecs.tools' from remote
>   source
>   'https://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='amazon.ecs.tools'&semVerLevel=2.0.0

Do I need to update my target feeds if so how do I do this I can't figure it out?

Comment: Check whether you have any connectivity issue with nuget endpoint. Also, try running same command with verbosity level and make sure you are on latest version of cli. `dotnet tool install --global Amazon.ECS.Tools --version 3.0.0 -v d`

Comment: didn't work and  dotnet --version
2.2.203, no issue with connectivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue. The global NuGet.config file in %appdata% was pointing to the wrong feed.